# Postcode search doesn't work in facebook postcode search

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

If you go to this site for the example `

[website](http://www.vestedutility.com.au/home_electrical_saftey_check.php)

i have 2 forms one is on the page (which i want to remove) the other im using facebox to bring it up when they click on orange button. The issue is the postcode search only works on the form on the page. I'm not sure why this is or how to get it working any ideas?

using http://defunkt.io/facebox/
script to search for the postcode

```
      $("#swSearch").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, add){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.vestedutility.com.au/wms/index.php/welcome/sw_search', //Controller where search is performed
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: req,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.response =='true'){
                   add(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i came up with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox(); 
          $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function(){
                $("[name=postal]").each(function(){ 
                    var sws=$(this);
                    if(sws.attr('data-advs')!='1') sws.attr('data-advs', '1').autocomplete({
                        minLength: 1,
                        source: function(req, add){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://www.vestedutility.com.au/wms/index.php/welcome/sw_search', //Controller where search is performed
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: req,
                                success: function(data){
                                    if(data.response =='true'){
                                       add(data.message);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
          });
          <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['action_info'])){ ?>$('#backface').click();<?php  session_unset(); } ?>
        })
    </script>
```